# Euler Number/Polynomial Identity

Tags: sequences-and-series, combinatorics, summation

If Euler numbers are defined as 
$$\frac{1}{\cosh{x}}=\frac{2}{e^x+e^{-x}}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty{E_n\frac{x^n}{n!}}$$
and Euler polynomials are defined as
$$\frac{2e^{xz}}{e^{x}+1}=\frac{2e^{xz}e^{\frac{-x}{2}}}{e^\frac{x}{2}+e^{\frac{-x}{2}}}=\frac{2e^{\left(z-\frac{1}{2}\right)x}}{e^\frac{x}{2}+e^{\frac{-x}{2}}}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty{E_n(z)\frac{x^n}{n!}}$$
How is it that we get
$$E_n\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)=2^{-n}E_n$$
I feel like the issue comes from the fact that
$$\frac{2e^{\left(z-\frac{1}{2}\right)x}}{e^\frac{x}{2}+e^{\frac{-x}{2}}}=\left(\sum_{n=0}^\infty{\frac{E_nx^n}{2^nn!}}\right)\left(\sum_{n=0}^\infty{\left(z-\frac{1}{2}\right)^n}\frac{x^n}{n!}\right)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\sum_{k=0}^n{\frac{E_k}{2^k}\left(z-\frac{1}{2}\right)^{n-k}\frac{x^n}{n!}}$$
Setting the summations equal produces
$$E_n(z)=\sum_{k=0}^n{\frac{E_k}{2^k}\left(z-\frac{1}{2}\right)^{n-k}}$$
Straight forward, i know that plugging in $z=1/2$ will give
$$E_n\left(\frac1{2}\right)=\sum_{k=0}^n{\frac{E_k}{2^k}0^{n-k}}$$
So why do we get this?  This implies that $0^0=1$. Is that just a definition or is there something else at work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$0^0 = 1$ is a convention, widely adopted with power series and such (particularly with generating functions in conmbinatorics), mostly to be able to write:

$$a_0 + a_1 z + \dotsb = \sum_{n \ge 0} a_n z^n$$

and have this work even when $z = 0$. It does make sense in this particular use, as $\lim_{z \to 0} z^0 = 1$.

Comment: I thought that had to be the case, but that whole indeterminant thing made me second guess it.   Thanks for the help.